# Plotting multiple dependent variables (classes) on a partial dependence repsonse curve (expressed as a probability) in R

Tags: r

I ran a random forest model in R and I am attempting to create partial dependence plots for the high importance predictor variables. I want to plot all the classes per plot. I am attempting to create something as shown in the figure below but like I said, I would want multiple classes plotted on the chart.

[image]

The script I have so far, is fairly clunky but it successfully creates a probability partial dependence chart per class. How can I get the chart to plot the probability of all classes per predictor variable. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
# Filter data for "Bog" class level
data_bog <- subset(data.train, Class_2 == "Bog")
# Create partial dependence data for the predictor variable DEV150_mean
pdp_dataB<- partial(rf_model, pred.var = "DEV150_mean", train = data_bog, class = "Bog", prob = TRUE, type = "classification")

# Plot the partial dependence chart for the "Bog" class in Class_2 for TRI_mean
pdp_plot3 <- autoplot(pdp_data, 
                      facets = TRUE, 
                      ylab = "Probability", 
                      xlab = "DEV150_mean") +
  ggtitle("Partial Dependence Plot for DEV150_mean (Bog)")

print(pdp_plot3)

##-TIDAL MARSH 

# Filter data for "Tidal Marsh" class level
data_TM <- subset(data.train, Class_2 == "Tidal Marsh")
# Create partial dependence data for the predictor variable DEV150_mean
pdp_datat<- partial(rf_model, pred.var = "DEM_mean", train = data_TM, class = "Tidal Marsh", prob = TRUE, type = "classification")

# Plot the partial dependence chart for the "TM" class in Class_2 for DEM_mean
pdp_plotT <- autoplot(pdp_datat, 
                      facets = TRUE, 
                      ylab = "Probability", 
                      xlab = "DEM_mean") +
  ggtitle("Partial Dependence Plot for DEM_mean (Tidal Marsh)")

print(pdp_plotT)
```